# What are the basic algorithms for text mining?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, text-mining

I'm trying to do an application for mining some texts from the web, but I'm not sure of what is the best way to perform text mining.

What I want with this question is know about what are the most used techniques/algorithms to perform text mining and do some information retrieval in documents (not for indexing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Text mining* is a rather broad term, it roughly means machine learning applied to text. Common techniques include *k*-means clustering, Naive Bayes and linear SVM classification, tf-idf vectorization, [SVD](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (called [LSA](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) when applied to text), latent Dirichlet allocation. So, performing "some text mining" might mean just about anything, just like doing "some information retrieval".

See Bing Liu's book *Web Data Mining* for a good intro to the field.

Answer (score 0):

I think [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is most used technique for [text mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining).

Answer (score -4):

Most basic text mining techniques is [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).